# Getting a value as -0.000000 on multiplying bigger values

Tags: c++, c

Why do i get a value as `-0.000000` . Does negative zero even exist?

I am multiplying to bigger double value. Why do i get a result like this?

Is it overflowing ? should i use a bigger data type than this?

Comment: I suggest that you read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 6):

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero):

```
 Does negative zero even exist?
```

> Signed zero is zero with an associated sign. In ordinary arithmetic, −0 = +0
>   = 0. However, in computing, some number representations allow for the existence of two zeros, often denoted by −0 (negative zero) and +0
>   (positive zero). This occurs in the sign and magnitude and ones'
>   complement signed number representations for integers, and in most
>   floating point number representations. The number 0 is usually encoded
>   as +0, but can be represented by either +0 or −0.

```
Is it overflowing ? should i use a bigger data type than this?
```

> In IEEE 754 binary floating point numbers, zero values are represented
>   by the biased exponent and significand both being zero. Negative zero
>   has the sign bit set to one. **One may obtain negative zero as the
>   result of certain computations, for instance as the result of
>   arithmetic underflow on a negative number, or −1.0*0.0, or simply as
>   −0.0**.

[image]

Comment: So are you saying this kind of cases(-1.0*0.0=-0.0) can not be avoided?

Comment: @james - It depends - if you can handle it then. That is the programmers overhead.

Comment: Additionally, the OP may simply have a small but non-zero negative value that is printed as “-0.000000” due to limited precision in the output format.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a sign magnitude thing. There exist 2 distinct values of zero in floating point types +0.0 and -0.0.
It could also be a precision thing. -0.000000000009 might be being printed as -0.000000, which it perfect reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

As is evident from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153771/how-can-i-avoid-0-0-in-computation), the value you have is not a negative zero but is a small negative value that is displayed as “-0.000000” because of the format specification used to display it.